# Selectively load parts of bootstrap in rails asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, asset-pipeline

```
Started GET "/assets/bootstrap-transition.js?body=1" for 64.124.65.162 at 2013-07-19   14:40:24 +0000
Served asset /bootstrap-transition.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap-button.js?body=1" for 64.124.65.162 at 2013-07-19 14:40:24    +0000
Served asset /bootstrap-button.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap-carousel.js?body=1" for 64.124.65.162 at 2013-07-19 14:40:24 +0000
Served asset /bootstrap-carousel.js - 304 Not Modified (9ms)
```

Above is a portion of my output from rails server.  If my application doesn't use a carousel, or plan to use one...I shouldn't load the javascript.  How do i choose which bootstrap files I would like to load?  I am using the bootstrap-sass gem and my application.js looks like

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following are the file names used by `bootstrap-sass` gem. Feel free to remove the plugins which you dont need. Files are listed [here](https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass/tree/master/vendor/assets/javascripts) and and its mentioned in the readme [here](https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass#javascripts)

```
//= require bootstrap-transition
//= require bootstrap-affix
//= require bootstrap-alert
//= require bootstrap-button
//= require bootstrap-carousel
//= require bootstrap-collapse
//= require bootstrap-dropdown
//= require bootstrap-modal
//= require bootstrap-scrollspy
//= require bootstrap-tab
//= require bootstrap-tooltip
//= require bootstrap-popover
//= require bootstrap-typeahead
```